# How to plot with ggplot grouped data in two levels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Here is my data set:

```
SP <- c("DC","DC","DP","DP","DC")
ES <- c("CA","CA","CA","CA","CK")
W <- c("B","A","B","A","B")
P <- c(0.5,0.77,0,0.43,.38)
df <- data.frame(SP, ES, W, P)
```

I would like to plot this like in the picture that I made in excel. It is important that the data are grouped and have the space between each of them.

Please find below my excel barplot:
[image]

Comment: Could you please add quotation marks around all the strings: e.g. `SP <- c("DC", "DC", ...)` to make your question reproducible. Note this includes the percentages, although it would be better if they were numeric ie `P <- c(0.5, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Using adapted data here is a replica of the excel version.
This method creates a dummy continuous variable: brks to set out the breaks for the columns (there may be a smarter way to generate this sequence by a formula, but as there are so few points I've done this manually). The x axis labels are created by combining the three variables, ordering and setting as factors to ensure they plot in the required order.

```r
dat <- data.frame(SP = rep(rep(c("DC", "DP"), each = 2), 3),
                  ES = rep(c("CA", "CK", "HD"), each = 4),
                  W = rep(c("B", "A"), 6),
                  P = c("50%", "77%", "5%", "43%", "38%", "68%", "3%", "26%", "13%", "5%", "2%", "4%"))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)


dat1 <- 
  dat %>% 
  arrange(ES, SP, desc(W)) %>% 
  mutate(P = as.numeric(str_extract(P, "\\d+"))/100,
         x_lab = fct_inorder(paste(W, ES, SP, sep = "\n\n")),
         brks = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17, 18, 20, 21))

ggplot(dat1, aes(brks, P))+
  geom_col(fill = "deepskyblue4", width = 0.95)+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(P, accuracy = 1)),
            vjust = 1.5,
            colour = "white",
            size = 3)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = dat1$brks, 
                     labels = dat1$x_lab)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)))+
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Using your original data, here is one approach using ggplot's `facet_wrap`.

Note: shadows are not good practice for graphs.

```r
dat <- data.frame(SP = rep(rep(c("DC", "DP"), each = 2), 3),
                  ES = rep(c("CA", "CK", "HD"), each = 4),
                  W = rep(c("B", "A"), 6),
                  P = c("50%", "77%", "0%", "43%", "38%", "68%", "0%", "26%", "13%", "5%", "0%", "4%"))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

dat %>% 
  mutate(P = as.numeric(str_extract(P, "\\d+"))/100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(SP, P, fill = W)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.8, reverse = TRUE))+
  facet_wrap(~ES, nrow = 1)+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(P, accuracy = 1)),
            position = position_dodge2(width = 0.8, reverse = TRUE),
            vjust = 1.5,
            colour = "white",
            size = 3)+
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(30, "mm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: please, I need one more thing. Can you add a code which will represent categorical value B or A under each bar?

Comment: See updated answer